# Different image source for different locales

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to have different image source for different browser locales?
The images are stored localy. One for english and another for german. So, if I start the browser in german language it must shown the german image. And the same for english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect the browser langauge via :

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
alert(language);
```

Now , you can check the value of `language` which can indicates where to read the images from.

Another option is to prefix the images with the language e.g. `en-USMyPic.jpg` , and then , via JS , read the image.

Comment: This helped me. I read the browser language as you said. The images names are _de.extensnion and _en.extension. And I set the image source like this, from js. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**:lang()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang) pseudo-class selector. Let the image sources have the `lang` attribute associated.

```css
:lang(en) {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
:lang(de) {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x300');
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div lang="en">For English users</div>
<div lang="de">For German Users</div>
```

Comment: I also found this solution on other sites, but it didn't helped me. Both divs are visible in the page, regardless the browser's language. But I will try again, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Oh right! :) Royi's solution was the way to go. Please try to explain the full problem next time, so you don't get broad answers.

Answer (score 0):

Manoj's answer doesn't quite answer the question. But a slight tweak could make it work.

Your typical markup would look something like this, with `lang` attribute defined on the `<html>` tag:

```
<html lang="en">
...
   <div class="lang-specific"></div>
...
</html>
```

The CSS would be something like:

```
:lang(en) .lang-specific {
   /* English styles here */
}

:lang(de) .lang-specific {
   /* German styles here */
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to define the lang into the html tag. The lang must be taken from the browser.

Comment: Well, then, Royi's answer is the way to go. You could also set the `lang` attribute for `<html>` tag using javascript, and that way you'd simply use CSS to style all language specific things you have in the document, instead of changing those styles dynamically using javascript.